# pandas - construct column depending on values in 2 separate columns of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a pandas dataframe which looks similar to this(i have cooked up an example, since I can't share the data)

```
raw_data = {'regiment': ['Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Scouts'], 
        'company': ['1st', '2nd', '1st', '2nd', '2nd'],  
        'thisValue': [1, 2, 3, 2, 7],
        'total': [3, 3, 5, 5, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['regiment', 'company', 'thisValue', 'total'])
df
```

The output is :

```
    regiment    company thisValue   total
0   Nighthawks  1st         1         3
1   Nighthawks  2nd         2         3
2   Dragoons    1st         3         5
3   Dragoons    2nd         2         5
4   Scouts      2nd         7         7
```

I want to have statistics about count of values of eachValue for a regiment. That is I need the resulting dataframe to be like this:

```
regiment    1stCompanyValue 2nd_Company_Value   total
Nighthawks         1               2              3
Dragoons           3               2              5
Scouts             0               7              7
```

I tried grouping it on company values, but then not sure how to proceed. How can this be done in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can make use of [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html),[`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) i.e

```
one  = df.pivot(columns='company',values='thisValue',index='regiment').add_suffix('_company_value').fillna(0)
two = df.groupby('regiment')['total'].first()

ndf = pd.concat([one,two],1)

              1st_company_value  2nd_company_value  total
regiment                                               
Dragoons                  3.0                2.0      5
Nighthawks                1.0                2.0      3
Scouts                    0.0                7.0      7
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. Can you please also give a small explanation?

Comment: ya, will do that :)

Comment: These are very simple functions, if I explain them I'm scared that I might confuse you so you can go for docs.  Pandas docs are really good for this.